Local existence NLS
I am reading the book of Tao on dispersive PDE. In a proof of local existence of the solution of NLS, he wrote that the following inequality holds:
$$||u|^{\alpha -1}u - |v|^{\alpha -1}v| \leq c (|u|^{\alpha -1} + |v|^{\alpha -1}) |u-v|. $$
I tried using triangle inequality but I do not get it. Can you help me, please?

Which page is the inequality on?

On page 135, if I remember correctly

If $\alpha >0$, it is a consequence of a Taylor inequality:
Let $\phi: E \rightarrow E$ (E is a Hilbert space) such that $\phi(x) = |x |^{\alpha - 1} x$. Then, by the fundamental theorem of analysis
$$||u|^{\alpha -1}u - |v|^{\alpha -1}v| = | \phi(u) - \phi(v)| = \left| 
\int_0^1 D\phi_{u+t(v-u)} (u-v) dt  \right|.$$
Since $\phi$ is essentially a "to the power $\alpha$" function, its differential satisfies $\| D\phi_x \| \sim |x|^{\alpha-1}$ for the operator norm. Therefore,
$$||u|^{\alpha -1}u - |v|^{\alpha -1}v| \le \int_0^1 |u+t(v-u)|^{\alpha-1} |u-v| dt .$$
If $\alpha \ge 1$, you have  $|u+t(v-u)|^{\alpha-1} \le C(|u|^{\alpha -1} + |v|^{\alpha -1})$ for all $t \in [0,1]$, which gives the result.

Okay. Thank you a lot
